# Is it possible to set powershell opacity through commandline

Tags: .net, powershell

New to powershell & .NET.

It is possible to [configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704393/317027) powershell console colors.

However how can i set the opacity of the window.  It seems that the `InternalHostRawUserInterface` class's property takes an enum `ConsoleColor`.

Is it possible to set the windows transparency?

Comment: Yes. If need be with a bit of custom C# code that does P/Invoke. Is your question rather "How do I do that?"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [Joey mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960519/is-it-possible-to-set-powershell-opacity-through-commandline/39961209#comment67200741_39960519), you'll have to talk to a low-level API to modify the transparency of the window.

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270316/cant-i-set-transparency-of-a-window-by-its-handle-in-c), we can adapt it to PowerShell like so:

```
function Set-ConsoleOpacity
{
    param(
        [ValidateRange(10,100)]
        [int]$Opacity
    )

    # Check if pinvoke type already exists, if not import the relevant functions
    try {
        $Win32Type = [Win32.WindowLayer]
    } catch {
        $Win32Type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
'@ -Name WindowLayer -Namespace Win32 -PassThru
    }

    # Calculate opacity value (0-255)
    $OpacityValue = [int]($Opacity * 2.56) - 1

    # Grab the host windows handle
    $ThisProcess = Get-Process -Id $PID
    $WindowHandle = $ThisProcess.MainWindowHandle

    # "Constants"
    $GwlExStyle  = -20;
    $WsExLayered = 0x80000;
    $LwaAlpha    = 0x2;

    if($Win32Type::GetWindowLong($WindowHandle,-20) -band $WsExLayered -ne $WsExLayered){
        # If Window isn't already marked "Layered", make it so
        [void]$Win32Type::SetWindowLong($WindowHandle,$GwlExStyle,$Win32Type::GetWindowLong($WindowHandle,$GwlExStyle) -bxor $WsExLayered)
    }

    # Set transparency
    [void]$Win32Type::SetLayeredWindowAttributes($WindowHandle,0,$OpacityValue,$LwaAlpha)
}
```

And then use it like:

```
Set-ConsoleOpacity -Opacity 50
```

Which will then set the opacity of the window to 50%

Comment: Works in real powershell. Does not work when powershell was started from cmd. My usage: script.ps1.cmd, allows drag and drop onto .cmd on every host. Bad luck :D.

Answer (score 0):

hold down control and shift, then move scroll wheel. This might be useless answer, I'm not sure if this is a permanent setting